# Wordpress is_user_logged_in && is_page not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Anyone can advise on why the following is not working, and maybe provide a better alternative?

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'shopping-cart' ) ) {
     echo '<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;">Please login in order to proceed with the checkout.</div>';
} else {
echo '<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;">You are logged in.</div>';
}
```

Basically I am not logged in, and the 'You are logged in' message still appears, on any page. I've added the code to the theme footer, if it matters.
Thank you.

Comment: I see you are passing 'shopping-cart' in is_page condition. can you check the page slug is right to match the condition.

Comment: id probs split that if statement up and nest them temporarily and throw some var dumps in there to see which one of those conditions its failing on first

Comment: the page slug is right

Answer (score 1):

Solved, thanks to Gautam [Golakiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772301/gautam-golakiya).
The page shopping-cart was generated by a plugin but did not exist in the Page section, so after creating a black page with the same slug, the code started to behave as it should. Basically nothing wrong with it.